# Python reference question, will this cause a memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, garbage-collection

Sorry for the vague question title but the question is to lengthy to put in the title. If someone can reword it better please do.

I have a reference based question regarding how objects are garbage collected. If I recall, objects are garbage collected when there are no more references to it. With that in mind will an object be deleted if all I have is a reference to one of its data members?

Here is a simple example of a class I am working with (mine is a lot bigger with a lot more functionality which is why I am creating a class instance within itself to handle the logic):

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_list = []

    def read_list_from_new_source(self):
        new_instance = A()
        for i in range(10):
            new_instance.add(i)

        self.my_list = new_instance.my_list

    def add(self, element):
        """
        Just adding an element to the list attribute of the class
        """
        self.my_list.append(element)
```

My question is, will `new_instance` be garbage collected after the `read_list_from_new_source` method finishes? Or will it stay in memory because `self.my_list` now holds a reference to one of it's attributes?

I know the `list` that `new_instance.my_list` references won't be deleted but my worry is the entire class instance will remain in memory.

My thought would be that since the object itself no longer has a reference, the object will be deleted and only the `list` will remain but I don't know of a way I can test this theory to make sure I don't have a memory leak.

Comment: **Python does not have pointers**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga references, sorry. I'll change the wording.

Comment: In any case, yes that instance will, since nothing references it after the function terminates

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you.